# Make ListActivity with Summary

Tags: java, android

How can I make a list with pictures and summary (the text under the item list text) it is little description to item.

My code makes a list with pictures. How can I add a Summary?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" >
 </TextView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
        // Use your own layout
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a costum listview with a costum layout.

In the internet you found a lot of good tutorials to teach you that.

Here is an example: 
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

The only difference to your case is that the image is on the left of the text and you want it on the top :).

If your list has always the same content you can create an adapter that already knows that content. Otherwise, you need to create a class to hold the type of content you will have on your list. It seems your content is static, so, I will suggest some lines for you to follow.

Mainly you have to create your adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };

    private int[] myImagesSaved = new Int[] { R.drawable.image1, 
                                              R.drawable.image2, ... }

    public MyAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
       super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }              

        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        ImageView image = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);

        if (text != null) 
           text.setText(values[position]);                            }

        if(image != null)
           image.setBackgroundResource(myImagesSaved[position]);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you just tell me what is the method for summary because i prefer to stay with my code. Thank you

Comment: Method for summary? What do you mean by that? If you want to adapt to your problem you can use your xml and almost the same code at your MyListActivity. You just need to create an adapter and the getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent). I will try to complete my answer with that.

Comment: Summary=little description under the item, it is like another text view.

Comment: your code give me an error `text.setText(values[position]);  ` here

Comment: Yes I can. In your code you use an adapter. However, your adapter only works with strings and only shows one string in each row. This code crates a new adapter, to show the strings in the variable value and the images in the variable myImagesSaved. Bascly you only have to declare this adapter and set it. 

So in myImagesSaved you should put the ids of your images. When you call MyAdapter you should pass the id of your row that was declared in your xml. And in getView we get the text and the image from that xml and we set them.

Answer (score 1):

Create Custom adapter for listview
If you want to customize the listview then you have to create a custom adapter.
There are some adapters like ArrayAdapter, BaseAdapter, CusrsorAdapter etc..
To create custom adapter extends on of the adapter class in your class and override methods.

Here is a link for custom adapter
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: Don't make me downvote you. You know this is not an answer of good enough quality.

Comment: can you please give me tutorial or give me the method to the Summary?

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Ya updating my answer

Comment: if i doing like this tutorial! and press First item is it give me individual Activity than the Second item? or there is some code that i should add it?